# How can I give a CSS grid element a fixed position while maintaining the grid position?

Tags: css, css-grid

Whenever I write

```
position:fixed;
```

for a grid element, the element's position goes to the top left corner and becomes fixed.  I want it to have a constant position in the viewport while maintaining its position in the grid.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Also, your description of what you want, "a constant position in the viewport while maintaining its position in the grid" is physically impossible.

Comment: @MrLister that's right.  I learned that I can fix my problem with position: sticky.  Thanks anyway.